# Existe a unique (weak) solution to a PDE's system with Robin condition.

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

**Q1)** Let consider the problem : $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$ open, bounded and smooth, $f\in L^1(\Omega )$, $g\in H^{-1/2}(\partial \Omega )$

$$\begin{cases}-\Delta u+u=f&\Omega \\ \partial _\nu u+u=g&\partial \Omega \end{cases}.$$

I have no problem to apply Lax-Milgram, but in which functional space do I have to solve the problem ? I mean, the weak equation 
$$\int_\Omega  \nabla \varphi\cdot \nabla u+\int_\Omega u\varphi+\int_{\partial \Omega }u\varphi=\int_\Omega  f\varphi+\int_{\partial \Omega }g\varphi,$$
but where do I take $\varphi$ ? in $H^1_0(\Omega )$ ? In $H^1(\Omega )$ ? Is there any compatibility condition ?

**Q2)** What is the weak formulation of the problem $$\begin{cases}-\Delta u=f&\Omega \\ u=g&\partial \Omega  \end{cases}\ ?$$
It's something like $$\int_\Omega \nabla u\nabla \varphi=\int_\Omega  f\varphi+\int_{\partial \Omega }g\varphi,$$
but where do I take $\varphi$ ? In $H_0^1(\Omega )$ ? in $H^1(\Omega )$ ? In an other space ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\textbf{Q1)}$ When you have your weak formulation you can see in which spaces the functions $u$ and $\varphi$ should be. Because of the first integral we know that $\vec{grad}\,\varphi \in L^2(\Omega)$ and $\vec{grad}\,u\in L^2(\Omega)$ and also their trace $\gamma:u=u|_\Gamma \in L^2(\Omega)$ and $\gamma:\varphi=\varphi|_\Gamma \in L^2(\Omega)$. Therefore it suffices for $u$ and $\varphi$ to be both in $H^{1}(\Omega)$.

$\varphi$ can not be in $H^1_0(\Omega)$ because you have a robin boundary condition on $\partial\Omega$. This problem is well posed whatever $f$ and $g$ you choose. Think about one material with volume $\Omega$ and surface $\partial \Omega$ that has sinks and sourced of heat inside $\Omega$ given by $f$ and on its boundary $\partial \Omega$ there is a convective heat exchange that depends on the outer temperature $u_0$ given by $g$.

$\textbf{Q2)}$ The weak formulation you have presented is wrong. The correct one is the following:
$$\int_\Omega{\vec{grad}\,u\cdot\vec{grad}\,\varphi\,dV}=\int_\Omega{f\varphi\,dV}+\int_{\partial\Omega}{\varphi\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}\,d\sigma}$$
 In this case you can choose the function space for $\varphi$ to be $H^1_0(\Omega)$, because (Q1 also apply here for the spaces) you do not have any information about the fluxes on $\partial\Omega$ of $u$ (given by its normal derivative $\partial_nu$)  and instead you have Dirichlet boundary conditions.

In this part you have compatibility conditions, because if you choose in your weak formulation $\varphi=1$ you must have:
$$\int_\Omega{f\,dV}+\int_{\partial\Omega}{g\,d\sigma}=0$$
This can be explained as done before. Imagine sources or sinks in your material with volume $\Omega$ and surface $\partial\Omega$ and a prescribed temperature on its boundary $\partial\Omega$. If there is no equilibrium between the gererated (extracted) heat given by $\int_\Omega{f\,dV}$ and the integral of the boundary temperature $\int_{\partial\Omega}{g\,d\sigma}$ the material cannot be in thermal equilibrium and the problem would not be well posed and it should not be stationary. This can be better explained if we set $g=0$, where $f$ has to be a function of zero mean, what means that the generated heat must be equal to the extracted heat, as it is required for the time derivative $\partial_t u=0$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your very constructive answer. Just one thing, since you talk about "having a sense" : If we have the problem $$\begin{cases}-\Delta u-u=f&\Omega \\ u=g&\partial \Omega \end{cases},$$ the weak formulation is $$\int_\Omega \nabla u\cdot \nabla \varphi+\int_\Omega  u\varphi=\int f\varphi+\int_{\partial \Omega}  g\varphi,$$ and this equation have sens for any $\varphi\in H^1$ and $u\in H^1$ (because if $\varphi\in H^1$, then $\varphi\in H^{1/2}(\partial \Omega )$) So why here we need to have the restriction of $\varphi\in H^1_0(\Omega )$ ?

Comment: I am so sorry. I did not see what you had for your weak formulation. I will edit my post accordingly. The last term in your weak formulation is wrong, it must contain the normal derivative of $u$, which is not known.

Comment: Thanks for the modification, i see better. But for the problem of my previous comment, why $\varphi\in H_0^1$ ? Because here we have that $g\in H^{1/2}(\partial \Omega )$ and thus the integral is well defined ? (I forgot to write this condition but $g\in H^{1/2}(\partial \Omega )$. To me, we could take $\varphi\in H^1$...

Comment: I did not mention that requirement, I say that $\varphi\in H^1(\Omega)$ not in $H^1_0(\Omega)$. If you require $\varphi\in H^1_0(\Omega)$ then you can not impose your Robin BC (you have a weak formulation exactly the same as for the question two, because the boundary integrals vanish.)  Functions $f$ and $g$ are supposed to be well defined under the integral sign, now you have clasify $u$ and $\varphi$ in their correct function spaces, and as I have said both need to be at least in $H^1(\Omega)$

Comment: And what is more $f$ bust be a function of $L^2(\Omega)$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer :) I know you didn't mention that $\varphi\in H_0^1$ for the robin condition. I was talking about the problem $$(P) : \begin{cases}-\Delta u-u=f&\Omega \\ u=g&\partial \Omega \end{cases}.$$ In my course they say that we must take $\varphi\in H_0^1$. But if I understood well, for Q1), you take $\varphi\in H^1$ because everything is well define in $H^1$. The weak formulation for $(P)$ is $$\int_\Omega \nabla u\nabla \varphi+\int_\Omega  u\varphi=\int_\Omega f\varphi+\int_{\partial \Omega } g\varphi.$$ Since all integrals are well defined

Comment: we could take $\varphi\in H^1$ instead of $H_0^1$. Is my question clear enough ? Let me know if it's unclear :)

Comment: Sorry, I mixed the problems. You are asking about another one.  The answer is that you choose the function spaces according to your weak form AND your boundary conditions. For the integrals for any Poisson problem (with a reaction term) to exist the base function space is always $H^1(\Omega)$ for $\varphi$. If you have Dirichlet BCs they force you to choose $\varphi\in H^1_0(\Omega)$ because you do not know $\partial _nu$ over $\partial\Omega$. Hope now it is clear, if not please ask.

Comment: And your weak formulation of the problem is again wrong. The last integral should be $$\int_{\partial\Omega}{\partial_n u\,\varphi\,d\sigma}$$

Comment: Ok, I see know (it's my false). Thanks a lot :-) I guess that for a Newman condition (i.e. the condition on $\partial \Omega $ is $\partial _\nu u=g$), then we can solve it in $H^1$ because we have information on every thing, right ? Thanks a lot for every thing, I think I get it :-)

Comment: Yes,  you are right. You are welcome.